# How can I change Box2D bodyDef type of an object after adding it to the world in Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have a basic 2d square class that has it's body type set to a Static Body. After the player presses a button on the UI I want to change the body type to a Dynamic Body.

When I change the object to a Dynamic Body within the render method nothing happens.

How can I change the Body Type so that it updates on the screen?

```
public void show() {
    ...
    s0 = new Square(-10, -20, 5, 5, 3);
    ground = world.createBody(s0.bodyDef);
    ground.createFixture(s0.fixtureDef);
    ground.setUserData(s0.sprite);
    s0.shape.dispose();
    ...
}

public void render(float delta) {
    ...
    if (ready) {
        s0.bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do your update of type is wrong, here you will re-set the type at each frame once *ready* is true.

Have you try this ?

```
s0.setBodyType(BodyType.DynamicBody)
```

EDIT : See comments below, you should update the body created from your world instead of the shape which is just a kind of prefab to create your body to your world

Comment: I have, it doesn't work.

Comment: Hmmm, can you do some other stuff to the body ? I mean, do they appears to be take in count ?

Comment: No nothing seems to update, interestingly if I print the changes to the output it shows the updated value. However nothing physically changes to the Body.

Comment: Only when I instantiate the `Square` it lets me set values.

Comment: I may be wrong, but i think the object you are manipulating is not the object that is displayed. Let me explain, you create a body to your world from a shape, and you're updating your shape instead of the world's body, try to get the body created from the world and apply change to this one, it should work ;)

Comment: Oh wow I didn't think about that at all it works now, thank you so much for your help!!